# Link Prediction Task on Multigraphs with GraphSAGE

Tags: graph-neural-networks, geometric-deep-learning, edge-detection, inductive-bias

I need to perform a link prediction task on a heteronegous multigraph (multi-node types, multi-edge types, multi-edges between pairs of nodes, node features and edge features) in the inductive setting.

I came across GraphSAGE that could perform this task in the inductive scenario, but I do not know whether it could be extended to the context of multigraphs that allow multiple edges (and edge types) between any two nodes. An idea I have in mind is to learn several graphs parallely, each graph consists of all nodes and all edges of an edge type. The problem is some edge features of an edge type can have influence on a connection of another edge type (For example, an attribute from edge type A between node 1 and 2 implies that node 1 and node 2 are connected with another edge type B). Could you help me to formulate the problem and suggest any direction to solve it? Thank you.